# Windows shell/command prompt?

Tags: shell, command-prompt

On the Windows operating system, the shell/terminal we have by default is the Command Prompt (CMD).

Now, when I use Linux (or even Mac) systems, I find that the terminal is generally a lot more full featured. The one I used made it easy to change settings and properties, was easily resizable, some even had line numbering and multiple tabs.

Since I've started programming, I've realized the importance of the command line, and I was wondering if there were any alternatives to the default Command Prompt? And, if there aren't many good alternatives, how would I go about writing my own? What would I have to take into consideration?

Comment: Install cygwin and add it to your path. There you can access most of the linux commands you access on your linux machines

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the Windows command prompt sucks. It is truly pathetic for 2011.

I use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)+[mintty](http://code.google.com/p/mintty/) instead.

---

If you miss Tilda/Guake/Yakuake (for Linux) or TotalTerminal (née Visor) (for OS X) try [mintty-quake-console](https://github.com/lonepie/mintty-quake-console).

---

#### Edit

Just came across another potential alternative, though I haven't tried it out yet: [Gow (Gnu on Windows)](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki).

Comment: This works without an additional layer, like cygwin: Windows Services for Unix http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=274 There is also GnuWin32 - http://sourceforge.net/projects/getgnuwin32/files/getgnuwin32/

Answer (score 4):

If you want a truly manly command line for Windows, use [PowerShell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa973757%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).